# What happens if someone changes a file content while doing the file downloading in MS Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, onedrive

We use the next MS Graph API endpoint to download a file content:

```
GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/content
```

Which is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

The endpoint returns a pre-authenticated download URL for the file.

Let's say we are downloading a big doc file and at the same time someone is modifying its content. Will this download URL point to the previous version of the file or it will somehow catch the newly edited version and I'll get not consistent content?

Comment: Once you started downloading the doc file, the file will be locked by Sharepoint/onedrive and it will download it. During the download time, if the user tries to update the file then they may get the error File is locked. Once the download operation finishes then the file will the unlocked.

Comment: Is that documented somewhere?